# How can I disallow NSDate to make automatic timezone conversion

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nsdateformatter

My web service returns the following date string in a JSON a response. This date string is already in UTC.

{"last_updated_at": "2012-11-19 07:55:30"}

I parse the response date string using NSDateFormatter like below.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

if ([ticketFields objectForKey:@"last_updated_at"] != [NSNull null]) {
    self.lastUpdatedAt = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[ticketFields objectForKey:@"last_updated_at"]];

    NSLog(@"Time Response string %@", [ticketFields objectForKey:@"last_updated_at"]);
    NSLog(@"Formatted NSDate %@", self.lastUpdatedAt);
}
```

Here is my log output

```
Time Response string 2012-11-21 11:38:44
Formatted NSDate 2012-11-21 06:08:44 +0000
```

As you can see, NSDateFormatter apart from parsing the date string, also thinks that the date string is in UTC+530 (my local timezone) and automatically converts it to UTC by subtracting 530 hours from the given date. I don't want this to happen. NSDateFormatter should convert dates as such from the given string and ideally give the following output.

```
Time Response string 2012-11-21 11:38:44
Formatted NSDate 2012-11-21 11:38:44 +0000
```

Answer (score 3):

This dataformater configuration prevented the conversion and considered the date response string to be a UTC date.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

And it worked.